# How do I mix live and "dead" content in my Elixir Phoenix LiveView app header?

Tags: http-headers, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I changed my root.html.heex file to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= @inner_content %>
  </body>
</html>
```

And moved the `<header>` element to be duplicated in `app.html.heex`:

```
<header>
  <section class="container w-full m-5 p-3 bg-blue-200 text-blue-600 text-5xl font-bold">
    <div class="text-2xl">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="float-left mt-1"
          src={Routes.static_path(@conn, "/images/logo.png")} alt="LOGO"/>
        <span class="flex text-4xl hover:text-blue-800">
          <span class="font-medium nomargin">WEBSITE</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <span class="float-right flex -mt-8 font-normal">
        <nav role="navigation">
          <%= render "_user_menu.html", assigns %>
        </nav>
      </span>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
<main class="container">
  <p class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><%= get_flash(@conn, :info) %></p>
  <p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><%= get_flash(@conn, :error) %></p>
  <%= @inner_content %>
</main>
```

...and in `live.html.heex`.

But I can't render "_user_menu.html" in `live.html.heex` because (of course) it uses `@current_user`.

Is there a trick that allows me to somehow have live content on the float-left side of the header and the  "_user_menu.html" fragment on the float-right side?

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you need to mix "Live" and "Dead" views/templates, there is `live_render/3` [documented here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.Controller.html#live_render/3). Been there, seen that [working] ;-)